# JSON to Store on Custom Object

Tags: json

I have a question on how can I store the JSON Returned Response (name, email) wherein I currently store all of it in a field in 
a form of JSON and store it on a custom object on a specific field like for example is EMAIL and name field? Meaning Parsing it first and store it on field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've JSON format something like below:

```
{
  "Name":"",
  "AccountNumber":"1312321"
}
```

then you can try like this:

```
String jsonString = '{"Name":"ABC","AccountNumber":"1312321"}';
Account act = (Account) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Account.class);
System.debug('Account:'+act.Name);
```

It works because JSON object's each field label matches with `Account` object.

Similarly if you've list of `Accounts` in your JSON then try like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name":"ABC",
    "AccountNumber":"1312321"
  },
  {
    "Name":"DEF",
    "AccountNumber":"456456"
  }
]
```

**Apex code for list of Accounts:**

```
String jsonString = '[{"Name":"ABC","AccountNumber":"1312321"},{"Name":"DEF","AccountNumber":"456456"}]';
List<Account> actList = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<Account>.class);
System.debug('Count:'+actList.size());
```

And finally if your mappings don't map with any of Standard/Custom Object, then you can create a Apex class with those JSON labels and parse your JSON to that ApexType. For Example:

**JSON String:**

```
{
  "price":100,
  "startDate":"09-09-2009",
  "endDate":"09-10-2009",
  "name":"IPHONE",
  "category":"Mobile"

}
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class CustomClass {
    public Integer price;
    public date startDate;
    public date endDate;
    public String name;
    public String category;
}
```

**Deserialize JSON:**

```
String jsonString = '{"price":100,"startDate":"09-09-2009","endDate":"09-10-2009","name":"IPHONE","category":"Mobile"}';
CustomClass obj = (CustomClass) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, CustomClass.class);
System.debug('CustomClass:'+obj.name);
```

Comment: but how do i store those json that been deserialize in a field in a custom objects

Comment: Retrieve that custom object record and use `JSON.serialize()` method. It will return a `String` containing JSON format of that record. Refer this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_class_System_Json).

Comment: You can't store deserialized objects in a field. But you can use a lookup field between these objects. childObject.LookupToDeserializedObject__c = JSON.deserialize(json, ParentObject__c.SObjectType);

Comment: it always have this error Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:170]

Comment: @Torrific post your code, it's hard to tell without looking at your code.

Comment: I have this code. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195841/parsing-a-json-to-be-stored-on-custom-object?noredirect=1#comment296080_195841 but this is for parsing only, I haven't stored it yet

Comment: How/When do we use this Apex code?