# Need help deserializing JSON response

Tags: apex, json, static-resources

I'm facing some issues with JSON deserializing. I have a JSON format data from my existing webservice and I have collected all that data and made a .txt file and uploaded as a static resource. So my question is, how can I utilize that static resource file in apex class ? Here is my JSON format Data :

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(19) {
    ["cso_no"]=>
    string(8) "13095524"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(10) "5000115236"
    ["vin_no"]=>
    string(17) "SAJBB4AG0HCY38725"
    ["dlrid"]=>
    string(5) "20067"
    ["current_allocation_dlr"]=>
    string(14) "Aditya Suzuki"
    ["brand"]=>
    string(6) "SUzuki"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "Baleno"
    ["submodel"]=>
    string(8) "TDI"
    ["engine"]=>
    string(8) "2.0 GTDi"
    ["ext_colour_code"]=>
    string(3) "1AA"
    ["ext_colour"]=>
    string(13) "Polaris White"
    ["int_colour_code"]=>
    string(3) "RNR"
    ["int_colour"]=>
    string(5) "Latte"
    ["model_yr"]=>
    string(4) "2017"
    ["mfg_yr"]=>
    string(9) "18-Jul-16"
    ["order_status"]=>
    string(12) "Dealer Stock"
    ["stock_status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["specification"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["show_fly"]=>
    string(1) "Y"
  }
    }
```

There are many more records like this. So, how can I parse this and get it to deserialize in a list or arrays?

I have tried to create a class for this as well. I'll show what I have done until now :

```
public class JSON2Apex {
    public static void consumeObject(JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }   

    public class JsonDeserialize {
        public String cso_no {get;set;} 
        public String product_id {get;set;} 
        public String vin_no {get;set;} 
        public String dlrid {get;set;} 
        public String current_allocation_dlr {get;set;} 
        public String brand {get;set;}  
        public String model {get;set;} 
        public String submodel {get;set;} 
        public String engine {get;set;} 
        public String ext_colour_code {get;set;} 
        public String ext_colour {get;set;} 
        public String int_colour_code {get;set;} 
        public String int_colour {get;set;} 
        public String model_yr {get;set;} 
        public String mfg_yr {get;set;} 
        public String order_status {get;set;} 
        public String stock_status {get;set;} 
        public String specification {get;set;} 
        public String show_udaan {get;set;} 

        public JsonDeserialize(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'cso_no') {
                            cso_no = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'product_id') {
                            product_id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'vin_no') {
                            vin_no = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'dlrid') {
                            dlrid = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'current_allocation_dlr') {
                            current_allocation_dlr = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'brand') {
                            brand = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'model') {
                            model = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'submodel') {
                            submodel = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'engine') {
                            engine = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'ext_colour_code') {
                            ext_colour_code = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'ext_colour') {
                            ext_colour = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'int_colour_code') {
                            int_colour_code = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'int_colour') {
                            int_colour = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'model_yr') {
                            model_yr = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'mfg_yr') {
                            mfg_yr = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'order_status') {
                            order_status = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'stock_status') {
                            stock_status = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'specification') {
                            specification = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'show_udaan') {
                            show_udaan = parser.getText();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex)System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }   
}
```

I'm new into this JSON parsing so dont know much about it. Can someone guide me through it.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195686/json-to-store-on-custom-object/195689#195689)

Comment: Does not look like json to my. Looks more like the output of a Javascript object???

Comment: Well, it is an array of data but i have similar to it in the json format. So any more suggestions on it ?

Answer (score 4):

Do ensure that your static resource is in [JSON format](http://json.org/); you can check that using a JSON validator e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

The [JSON.deserialize(jsonString, apexType)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) method is the first thing to try as it does *all* the deserializing work for you. That work is controlled by the second argument, and the simplest way to generate that class is to give [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) an example of your JSON and let it work out the corresponding class definitions.

So the deserialization becomes this simple:

```
public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
}
```

(JSONParser requires you to do a lot of coding that embodies the expected structure - very error prone and hardly ever necessary to do.)